# select query result as insert statements

Tags: mysql

Imagine you have 2 databases : xpto & zpto. I want to do a select query in db xpto, export it as insert statements and import those insert statements in database zpto. Is this possible ?

Edit: I really need a dump because databases are not in the same machine and I don't have remote access to zpto.

Comment: I don't understand why this question was voted down ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
insert into zpto.table select * from xpto.table where .......
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-database-export.htm

(Section copying tables or databases to another host)

```
mysqldump -u root -p xpto table_name > dump.txt
mysql -u root -p zpto < dump.txt
```

If you have PHPMyAdmin, you can use the export / import facility to do exactly what you are after.

Comment: This is not enough because I don't want all the data in table_name, only some rows filtered by a where clause.